# Partial Implicit Differentiation

Tags: partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation, population-dynamics

I am currently writing a paper related to spotted owl conservation and reading a [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/4218620.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3Ab76b2102ba10df0bbfd9e7ae96eb716a&ab_segments=&origin=) about demographic models for that species. It uses the Euler-Lotka equation, along with some facts about owl biology, to find a reduced characteristic equation $$\lambda ^ \alpha (\alpha-s/\lambda) = l_\alpha b,$$ where $\lambda$ is the population's growth rate, $\alpha$ Is the age of first reproduction, $s$ is the probability of an adult individual surviving to the next year, $l_a$ is the probability of a juvenile surviving to reproduction age, and $b$ is the number of offspring per capita. ADDITIONALLY, $l_\alpha = s'_0s_ds_1s$ (essentially the product of the probability it survives its dispersal times the probability it survives 2 more years—but this understanding is not necessary to the calculation).

I understand up to here, but then the authors embark on a sensitivity analysis for each of the variables using implicit partial differentiation, concepts which I think I understand fairly well. However, I cannot find the specific process the authors use to get this result: [image].

Could someone please explain step-by-step how the authors reach these results. Thank you very much!

Edit: This is the work that I have so far for $\partial{\pi}$. $$\frac{\partial}{\partial{s_d}}[\lambda^\alpha(1-s/\lambda)] = \frac{\partial}{\partial{s_d}}[s'_0s_ds_1sb]$$ $$(\frac{\partial}{\partial{s_d}}[\lambda^\alpha])(1-s/\lambda) + \lambda^\alpha(-s\frac{\partial}{\partial{s_d}}[1/\lambda]) = s'_0s_1sb$$ $$\alpha\lambda^{\alpha-1}\frac{\partial{\lambda}}{\partial{s_d}}(1-s/\lambda) + \lambda^\alpha(-s*-1/\lambda^2\frac{\partial{\lambda}}{\partial{s_d}}) = s'_0s_1sb$$ Aside from factoring $\frac{\partial{\lambda}}{\partial{s_d}}$, I am stuck as to where to go from here.

Comment: Did you try taking $\partial_{\pi}, \partial_{s}$ and $\partial_{\alpha}$ of both sides of the equation?

Comment: Yes I have; I think I must be making some error in the differentiation or more likely I am failing to see some simplification in the resulting algebra.

Comment: You should probably add it to your post then.

Comment: @mattos I just did so.

Comment: Do you mean $\alpha$ in place of $a$?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Yes I did. I have corrected it.

Comment: Why is $l_\alpha$ written as such? Do the parameters it is comprised of depend on $\alpha$?

Comment: I should have clarified that $\alpha$ Is the age of first reproduction. So la is the probability of surviving to reproduction age.